# Windows 10 login screen "The filename or extension is too long" when entering a long string in the username box

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

I noticed an unusual issue on the Windows 10 login screen. When I type a very long string of dashes (I am not sure how many, I just held it for 20 seconds) in the username box, and try to log in with it, I get the error message "The filename or extension too long". The way I found out about this was I had a binder on my keyboard, and then I got this error message, so I tried typing a long string, and it gave me the same message.

I am still able to log in, but this is really confusing me.

Is there a reason why this error message is showing, and is this by design?

Screenshots: [Login screen with username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LmVb.jpg) and [Login screen with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PrN6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a maximum user name length that is enforced within Windows, and it is probably safe to say that your tests exceeded that limitation.

For example, previous versions of Windows had a [limitation of 104 characters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726984.aspx):

> Logon names can be up to 104 characters. However, it isn't practical to use logon names that are longer than 64 characters.

As the reference said, for practical purposes it is difficult to imagine anyone wanting to utilize a logon name longer than that.